# Put two commands after an ||

Tags: bash

I'd like to check to make sure a handful of commands are available. If it's not, I'd like to print an error message and then exit.

I'd like to do this without checking variables, because it's a small point in the script and I don't want it to sprawl over a bunch of lines.

The shape I'd like to use is basically this:

```
rsync --help >> /dev/null 2>&1 || printf "%s\n" "rsync not found, exiting."; exit 1
```

Unfortunately, the `exit 1` is executed regardless of the rsync result.

Is there a way to use this perl-type die message in bash, or no?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To directly answer the question, braces group commands together, so:

```
rsync --help >> /dev/null 2>&1 || { printf "%s\n" "rsync not found, exiting."; exit 1; }
```

As a suggestion for doing what you want, but in another way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for c in rsync ls doesnotexist othercommand grep
do
  if ! type "$c" &> /dev/null
  then 
    printf "$c not found, exiting\n"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

And if you want to emulate perl's `die` in shell:

```
function die {
  printf "%s\n" "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}

# ...
if ! type "$c" &> /dev/null
then
  die "$c not found, exiting"
fi
# ...
```

Comment: Note that that `cmd &> /dev/null` means something different in POSIX shells. That's running `cmd` in background and then do a command-less redirection to /dev/null. Also note the `die()` standard syntax as opposed to the `function die` ksh one.

Comment: Excellent point, as always; I've added a bash she-bang line; otherwise, simply use `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: also repointed `function die` to stderr `>&2` to better simulate perl's die()

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I prefer >& for my muscle memory because it works in more shells and tends to hard-fail in shells that don't support it. I don't know where people pick up the habit of using &>

Comment: @Random832 Probably by analogy with `2>`.

Comment: I usually use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` in the `die` function definition, so I have the flexibility for multi-line error messages should I want it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Wildcard! I've edited it in. I briefly chased the idea of emulating perl's die a bit more (BASH_LINENO and FUNCNAME arrays), but stopped short.

Answer (score 5):

Does it need to be a one-liner? I'm not a big fan of short-circuiting. I would write it like this:

```
if ! rsync --help &>/dev/null; then
    printf "%s\n" "rsync not found, exiting."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (as you may want to do the same thing in several places) is to define a function:

```
die()
{
    echo "$@" >2
    logger -t "$0" -- "$*"
    exit 1;
}
```

Notice that `die` sends its error message to standard error - you'll want this in the general case.  I also send a message to syslog (the script I took this from is long-running) but you don't need to do that if you don't want to.

You can then use this simply:

```
rsync -q --help 2>&- || die "rsync not found, exiting."
```

I also used `rsync -q` to suppress the help output in the success case.  In fact, you may find that you're happy with the behaviour of

```
set -e
rsync -q --help
```

which, if there's no `rsync` on `$PATH`, will report

> `$0`: rsync: command not found

(with your script name in place of `$0`) and exit with status 127.